# I cannot import LightningStrikle geometry in threejs

Tags: three.js

I wanted to create a lightning strike effect in threejs. And I learnt it from some nice video tutorials but

1. the threejs lightning strike examples page they showed in the video seems to be removed (i cannot find it)
2. if i open that same example from another website (http://www.yanhuangxueyuan.com/threejs/examples/webgl_lightningstrike.html) & copy its code, vite says that it could not find any LightningGeometry.js in addons
3. not a single javascript file succeds to load if i use the standalone version of that example (that is if i copy the entire code of that example, which uses cdn & works perfectly)

What to do? How do i import the LightningStrike? I really need it. And how can that website import & use all required libraries of threejs when i with the exact same code cannot?